# Access template inner typedef

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, using

I attach (again, the first post we buggy) the following code.

It doesn't compile with VS2012:

```
struct POD1
{
    int x; 
};

struct POD2
{
    char x; 
};

class A
{
public:
    typedef POD1 innerType;
    void doSomthing(POD1 t);
};


class B
{
public:
    typedef POD2 innerType;
    void doSomthing(POD2 t) { }
};


template<typename T>
class X
{
public:
    using myType = typename T::innerType;   // Doesn't work
    void foo(myType  bar) {}  // Doesn't work
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    X<B> x;
    POD2  b; 
    x.foo(b);


    return 0;
}
```

The errors I get:

```
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\try\try\try.cpp(36): error C2873: 'myType' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>          c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\try\try\try.cpp(38) : see reference to class template instantiation 'X<T>' being compiled
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\try\try\try.cpp(36): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '='
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\try\try\try.cpp(36): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\try\try\try.cpp(37): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'myType'
```

**EDIT** 
template aliasing doesn't work (yet) with VS2012.
Any workarounds?

Guy

Comment: Can you show *how* you use `X`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: see attached

Comment: @billz sorry about that

Comment: doesn't foo function take a parameter?

Comment: did you switch the C++11 compiler flag on?

Comment: You need to pass an argument to `x.foo()`. It [works with g++](http://ideone.com/lGuW0h). But you need C++11 support, of course.

Comment: Walter: Not sure that there's a c++11 flag, but it works 
@juanchopanza: doesn't work with VS 2012

Comment: @GuyL Right, if you're stuck with VS, then you will need to use the old-school `typedef` formulation.

Comment: In other words, `typedef typename T::innerType myType`.

Comment: Looks like somebody beat me to it :)

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thanks, I totaly forgot about `typedef typename` thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple typedef should work:

```
template<typename T>
class X
{
public:
    typedef typename T::innerType myType;
    void foo(myType  bar) {}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx) you will see that alias templates is not supported in VS2012. So that feature can't be used just yet.